# Why can't i listen to remote connections?

Tags: tcplistener

I want to listen to connections from remote machines. However its not working. Using my browser i just simply connect to 127.0.0.1 and i know if i connected or not (both from the browser message and debugger).

127.0.0.1 works as does 127.0.0.2. But 192.x.x.x does not unless i use IPAddress.Parse("192.168.1.1") (assuming thats my local address). But any is suppose to work for any interface. Whats wrong with this? [DoBeginAcceptTcpClient looks like this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.tcplistener.beginaccepttcpclient.aspx). The problem still exist for ports >1024. I tested with 1234

```
var server = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, 80);
server.Start(backlog);
while (true)
{
    DoBeginAcceptTcpClient(server);
}
```

Comment: Maybe you firewall is blocking incoming connections?

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz Theres no firewall on 192... also changing nothing but the bind address makes 192 address work. `.Any` is suppose to listen to that

Comment: Hm, one thing i can think of is wildcards. Does this method accept addresses like "\*.\*.\*.\*" or "\*"?

Comment: @KevinMangold Actually, this came because of that. I notice that `.Any` was NOT receiving remote connections which is exactly what i wanted. But that seem suspicious especially since you said it will receive remote connections. My server would eventually need external IPs to connect so i tried `.Any` and other code and i cant get any connections from outside my machine.

Comment: This sounds like a firewall issue. Check your OS settings and router settings. I deleted the original comment because after reading the question more carefully, I noticed it was different.

Comment: The solution was firewall issues. Especially when port 80 is being used.